# Is it correct to say that a linear equation is an equation in which the highest degree is $1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I see linear equation is commonly described as "an equation in which the highest degree is 1".

But consider this:

$$2x + x^{1/2} = 3$$

In this equation, the highest degree is 1, but this is not a linear equation.

What am I missing?

Comment: If it is phrased with "highest degree is 1" then someone is assuming it is a polynomial equation in the first place. And variable terms only appear with nonnegative integer powers.